# call a contract function which creates a new contract in web3.js makes an error VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, dapps, ganache

At first I'm developing with truffle v5.1.34, Node v10.16.0, Web3 v1.2.4
To make it simple, I have a Two contracts, DApp and User
What i'm doing is call a DApp contract function which creates a new User Contract like below

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;


contract User {
    string private _name;
    string private _publicKey;

    constructor (string memory name, string memory publicKey) public  {
        _name = name;
        _publicKey = publicKey;
    }


    function getName() public view returns(string memory) {
        return _name;
    }

    function getPublicKey() public view returns(string memory) {
        return _publicKey;
    }

}
```

This is a User SmartContract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./domain/User.sol";
import "./common/Ownable.sol";


contract DApp is Ownable {
    address [] private _userList;

    constructor () public Ownable(msg.sender) {

    }

    function createUser(string memory name, string memory publicKey) public {
        User user = new User(name, publicKey);
        address userAddr = address(user);
        _userList.push(userAddr);
    }

    function getUserList() public view returns(address[] memory) {
        return _userList;
    }

}
```

This is a DAppContract which creates user contracts.
When I call this function in a truffle console, it doesn't make any errors and works well.
But when i call this function in a javascript with web3.js it makes an error like below
[image]

```js
        // account and dapp is in another code
        await dapp.methods.createUser("Test", "Test").send({
            from: account
        });
```

As a i test this code by add new User code in constructor or in truffle console, getUserList returns well but only with web3 library makes an error
VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error?

Comment: Your code seems fine try setting gas to 2M. If it is not specify it will default to a hardcoded value that might not be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, It really solved!!!

Answer (score 1):

You try create new `User`:

```
User user = new User(name, publicKey);
```

But `User` constructor does not have arguments:

```
constructor () public  {

}
```

Comment: oh sorry it was mistake and i edit my question. This one occurs an error